# How can I remove a SoundCloud preview on a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, music, soundcloud

I added a SoundCloud link in a post on Facebook a while ago:

[image]

How can I remove the preview?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the preview.

You'll have to delete that update and post a new status update without the link/preview to SoundCloud.